# CloudStack and Cloudify compatibility

Tags: cloud, jclouds, cloudify

There is compatibility requirements everyone should be clear of before working bring Cloudify and CloudStack together. For the most part from what I can see Cloudify depends on JClouds for its CloudStack and probably other vendors API integration. So its worth checking the version of JClouds your Cloudify is dependant on and then see what JClouds version matrix is.

### Cloudify 2.1 (Current Release)

- JCloud 1.4.0
- Cloudstack 2.2

### Cloudify 2.2

- JCloud 1.4.0
- Cloudstack 2.2

### Cloudify 2.3 (You can build this from source)

- JCloud 1.5.2
- Cloudstack 3.0

With CloudStack 3.0 came significant changes that meant the API was not backward compatible, thus requiring JClouds to change their API implementation.

Please do not try and run Cloudify 2.1 / 2.2 with CloudStack 3.0 after alot of debugging they would not work due to a change in the data type for the Template Id in CloudStack from long in 2.2 to String in 3.0. There was one request which touched on this, but did not provide explanation as to why. https://cloudifysource.zendesk.com/entries/21757916-deploying-on-cloudstack

I hope this helps someone else who trying to put these versions together, just dont.

For CloudStack 3.0 use Cloudify 2.3 and above.  I put this to support the community and does not need to be answered but will provide an overview of compatibility matrix.  I hope this is helpful

Thanks,

Noel

Comment: You must post this in the Q&A format: ask a question and answer it yourself. This way it has already been flagged as "not a real question".

Answer (score 0):

From the question and answer above you should be familiar with the compatibility between Cloudify, Cloudstack and JCloud

### Cloudify 2.1 (Current Release)

- JCloud 1.4.0
- Cloudstack 2.2

### Cloudify 2.2

- JCloud 1.4.0
- Cloudstack 2.2

### Cloudify 2.3 (You can build this from source)

- JCloud 1.5.2
- Cloudstack 3.0